# Passed a filename that is NOT a string of characters! (RMarkdown)

Tags: r, r-markdown, ncdf4

I'm accessing ncdf files directly from a website [here][1] into my RMarkdown.
When I try to read the file using the nc_open functions as in the code below, I get the error  'Passed a filename that is NOT a string of characters!'
Any idea how I can solve this?
ps: I even tried uncompressing the files with the gzcon function but the result is the same when I try to read the data.
Thanks for your help!
Kami

```
library(httr)
library(ncdf4)
nc<-GET("https://crudata.uea.ac.uk/cru/data/hrg/cru_ts_4.05/cruts.2103051243.v4.05/pre/cru_ts4.05.2011.2020.pre.dat.nc.gz")
cru_nc<-nc_open(nc)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK here is the fill answer:

```
library(httr)
library(ncdf4)
library(R.utils)
url <- "https://crudata.uea.ac.uk/cru/data/hrg/cru_ts_4.05/cruts.2103051243.v4.05/pre/cru_ts4.05.2011.2020.pre.dat.nc.gz"
filename <- "/tmp/file.nc.gz"

# Download the file and store it as a temp file
download.file(url, filename, mode = "wb")

# Unzip the temp file
gunzip(filename)

# The unzipped filename drops the .gz
unzip_filename <- "/tmp/file.nc"

# You can now open the unzipped file with its **filename** rather than the object
cru_nc<-nc_open(unzip_filename)
```

Comment: Thank you @CALUM Polwart

Answer (score 0):

Is this a mode="w" Vs mode="wb" issue. I've had this with files before. No experience of ncdf4.

Not sure if you can pass mode="wb" to get but does

file.download(yourUrl, mode="wb")

Work / help

---

Edit:

Ah. Other thing is you are storing the object as an object (nc) but nc_open wants to open a file.

I think you need to save the object locally (unless nc_open can just take the URL) and then open it? Possibly after unzipping.

Comment: Thank you but, unfortunately, changing the mode doesn't solve the issue.